# How to solve 403 error when restarting PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, apache

I have a server running on CENTOS 8, with Apache 4.2 and PHP-FPM.

When i restart the service PHP-FPM i get a 403 forbidden error.

This happen because the owner of `/run/php-fpm/www.sock` becomes `root` instead of the Apache running user.

I have tried, without success, to edit `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` file

```
; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660
```

How i can restart PHP-FPM without changing every time the owner of the socket?

Answer (score 0):

try to add: `listen = /path/to/unix/socket` and make sure that the service uses the right socket file.

Comment: i already have `listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock` and it's the right socket

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The issue was `listen.acl_users`.

When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored.

**Solution:** comment out this line:

`;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx`